# How to change Watcher module's time format so it only displays the time in one line?

Tags: entities, datetime

I am using the [Watcher](http://drupal.org/project/watcher) module for a client's site. I am looking for a way to change the time format so instead of saying *2 days 20 hours ago*, it says *2 days ago*. Of course, it seems to be OK when it is something just posted, and it says *X seconds/minutes/hours ago* only.